# How to do Rank based- inverse normal transformation using Stata (from R)

Tags: r, transformation, stata

I have this function in R (`rntransform {GenABEL}`) which does inverse-normal-rankBased-transformation on a variable and would like to do the same in Stata. However, I cannot seem to decipher the last step (`qnorm(out)`):

```
function (formula, data, family = gaussian) 
{
    if (is(try(formula, silent = TRUE), "try-error")) {
        if (is(data, "gwaa.data")) 
            data1 <- phdata(data)
        else if (is(data, "data.frame")) 
            data1 <- data
        else stop("'data' must have 'gwaa.data' or 'data.frame' class")
        formula <- data1[[as(match.call()[["formula"]], "character")]]
    }
    var <- ztransform(formula, data, family)
    out <- rank(var) - 0.5
    out[is.na(var)] <- NA
    mP <- 0.5/max(out, na.rm = T)
    out <- out/(max(out, na.rm = T) + 0.5)
    out <- qnorm(out)
    out
}
```

Does someone know how to do this in Stata?

It should be something like

```
  egen stdVar = std(Var)
  egen stdVar_rank=rank(stdVar)-0.5
  egen max= max(stdVar_rank)
  replace max = 0.5/max
  replace  stdVar_rank= stdVar_rank/max
  gen InvRankNormVar =  qnorm(stdVar_rank) -->?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is documented in various places, e.g.

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentile-ranks-and-plotting-positions/

http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0027

In terms of your code:

1. (Statistics) Standardizing a variable before ranking does no harm but is quite unnecessary as the ranks of a standardized variable are just the same as those of the variable itself.
2. (Stata) Putting a constant in a variable (i.e. in every observation or row of a dataset) is usually also unnecessary.
3. (Statistics) You should scale rank by the number of values, not the maximum rank. If several values tie for maximum, the highest rank observed will be less than the number of values. (Toy example: the 5 values 1, 2, 3, 3, 3 will rank 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, so the highest rank is 4, not 5.)
4. (?) I can't fathom what you are trying to do with the line `replace max = 0.5/max`
5. (Stata) There is no function `qnorm()`; the one you want is called `invnormal()`, as `help functions` would tell you.

I think what you want is

```
egen rank = rank(Var)
su Var, meanonly 
gen InvRankNormVar = invnormal((rank - 0.5) / r(N))
```

where the number of non-missing values as `r(N)` is accessible immediately after `summarize`.

P.S. I didn't try reading your R code. I qualify only as a R beginner.

Comment: Thank you, i noticed the first site already. gen var = qnorm() does not work in my stata(v11/v12); is that correct ? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Quite so. Thanks for quick attention to all concerned.

Answer (score 2):

try this ado code (equivalent of a R function in Stata) in case you want to use this calculation again. keep the ado file at `C:/ado/personal/_/_gnormalize.ado` (or whatever the location of your personal ado files is):

```
program define _gnormalize
    version 9.2
**************************************[ NORMALIZE ]********************************
* 
* This function converts a raw factor into normalized Z-Score
*   option `1' is the raw factor
*   option `2' is additional grouping, e.g. sector
*
**************************************[ NORMALIZE ]*******************************

    gettoken type 0 : 0
    gettoken g    0 : 0
    gettoken egs 0 : 0
    syntax varlist(min=1) [, BY(string)]

    if `"`by'"'!="" {
        local by `"by `by':"'
    }

    quietly {
        gen `type' `g' = .
        `by' egen `g'rank = rank(`varlist'), unique
        `by' egen `g'count = count(`varlist') if `varlist'~=.
        replace `g'=invnormal((`g'rank-0.5)/`g'count) if `varlist'~=.
        drop `g'rank `g'count
    }
end
```

usage is as follows:

```
bysort month sector: egen my_transscore = normalize(my_factor)
```

where the `by` variables `month`, `sector`, etc. are optional (i.e. `bysort month sector:` are optional and for usage in case you want to do the operation by groups)

Comment: This program needs to support `if` and `in` and avoid `egen` calls within `egen`, if only as a matter of efficiency. As explained in my answer to this question, the use of a variable to contain a constant is poor style. It wires in the `unique` option of `rank()`, which may or may not be desired. The name `normalize` is also possibly ambiguous. Most importantly, this program **does not calculate z-scores**. That is a major misunderstanding.

Comment: @Nick, hope all is well. all very valid points and duly noted. "normalize" is a common name used for this transformation in cross-sectional stock-selection finance, but I agree its not the best name. I guess, the code might just do the job for the OP. I up voted your above comment (leaves something for me to implement whenever I get more time).

Comment: @Nick, thinking more about it: it might still make sense to use a variable to contain a constant if the "`by`" grouping variables are supplied, else the code may become complicated to handle cases when a "`by`" group is supplied or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are correct that use of `by:` necessitates use of a variable. But you don't address what I flag as most important: your program does not calculate z-scores in the usual sense of (value - mean)/SD. These are normal quantiles. Otherwise put, a serious program requires a help file. If you want to leave this as code that people may or may not want to adopt or adapt, we must hope that people understand exactly what the code does and doesn't do.

Comment: @Nick, done (no more reference to zscore). unfortunately, I don't have the time for a deeper help file at present. as always, I appreciate your concerns. please feel free to edit the code above (I suspect you have edit permissions).

Comment: Thanks for your attention and your generous offer, but I'll leave the code as it is. My line as already indicated is that you can do this in a very few lines with existing functionality. That doesn't stop anyone writing their own program so that you can do it in one.